# Делегат постоянно равен nil

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

Я использую `viewdeck` для отображения сайдбара.
В классе `viewController` создаю `tableview` и протокол для изменений в классе `secondviewController`

```
@protocol ReloadCollectionView <NSObject>
-(void)myMethod;
@end

@interface ViewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<ReloadCollectionView> delegate;
```

В `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` связываю событие

```
[delegate myMethod];
```

Далее в `SecondViewController`:

```
ViewController *vc = [[ViewController alloc]init];
vc.delegate = self;
```

Однако метод `-(void)myMethod`; не вызывается. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Может ли быть такое, что вы устанавливаете делегат одному объекту, а didSelectRowAtIndexPath вызывается у другого?

Comment: Нет, не то

Answer (score 2):

Я когда-то задавал очень похожий вопрос на SO и сам же на него отвечал: [The right way of setting up MapKit's delegate in a separate class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12415991/the-right-way-of-setting-up-mapkits-delegate-in-a-separate-class).

Вам нужно сделать

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) id<ReloadCollectionView> delegate;
```

чтобы ваш delegate удерживался (retained) после своей инициализации.

Наверняка вы привыкли видеть декларацию **(nonatomic, weak)**, которую автоматически устанавливает Xcode при установке делегата через Storyboard. Так вот, в случае, когда делегат установлен в storyboard, мы (или чаще Xcode за нас) объявляем в контроллере **(nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet...**, так как в этом случае Storyboard удерживает (retains) делегат после его создания. В вашем же случае ваш делегат (судя по отсутствию декларации **IBOutlet**) создаётся вами вручную в отдельном классе, поэтому вам нужно изменить **weak** на **strong**. Вот документация по поводу weak, strong и др.: [Objective-C Automatic Reference Counting (ARC) - Property declarations](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html#property-declarations).

Если же вдруг декларация **@property(nonatomic,weak) ... delegate** или **@property(nonatomic,assign) ... delegate** уже существует и вы не можете её менять (например, вы создаёте подкласс UIScrollView и декларация delegate уже наследована и существует в вашем подклассе), вам придётся создать дополнительное свойство @property (strong, ...) ... delegateClass для вашего класса-делегата - смотрите, как это делается в моём вопросе на SO. Но прежде, чем делать это, прочитайте мой ответ до конца.

Добавлю ещё про делегаты: странно видеть, что вы создаёте делегат в контроллере (для контроллера). Я не гуру паттернов проектирования Apple, но в целом, как мне кажется, контроллеры как раз и предназначены для того, чтобы служить полем для встречи всех возможных делегатов от разных "не-контроллерных" по своей сути объектов, например, views (scroll views, карт, текстовых полей и т.д.). Действительно, может оказаться, что плоды работы вашего контроллера могут понадобиться где-то ещё, но скорее это будут просто контроллеры-родители в иерархии контроллеров и вашему контроллеру в этом случае не нужно будет иметь делегатов от них или становится им самому.

То есть, иными словами, наиболее часто встречающийся вариант использования делегатов: делегация "не-контроллерными" по своей сути объектами ключевой части своей логики контроллерам, где эта логика может встретиться и пересечься с остальной логикой вашего приложения (примеры: UITableView, MKMapView, NSURLConnection).

Простой пример: в контроллере FooController

```
@interface FooController : UIViewController <BarViewDelegate>...
// ...
@implementation FooController
// ...
BarView *barView = [BarView alloc] init];
barView.delegate = self;
```

То есть в контроллерре FooController создаётся view типа BarView, и FooController будет служить делегатом для barView.